# jquery animate multiple elements with delay

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to animate multiple elements with jQuery one after another, so

```
$("div").each(function(i){
    $(this).delay(i*1000).animate({left: "+=200"}, {duration: 3000});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eP2C3/1/
And now I need them to fadeOut while moving. If duration is 3000ms I add 2500ms delay and fade it out in 500ms.

```
$("div").each(function(i){
    $(this).animate({left: "+=200"}, {duration: 3000, queue: false})
            .delay(2500)
            .animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 500});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eP2C3/
But if I combine it with previous example they would animate simultaneously. And delay only opacity animation.

```
$("div").each(function(i){
    $(this).delay(i*1000).animate({left: "+=200"}, {duration: 3000, queue: false})
            .delay(2500)
            .animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 500});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eP2C3/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the `queue: false`. The `delay()` will be ignored if you specify the animation not to be queued because delay is a callback that is also added to the queue.

Here I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eP2C3/10/

---

Update:

If you need `opacity` animation to start after 2500ms from the start left animation then `queue: false` should be applied to do this. However `.delay(i*1000)` will be ignored but a good workaround is to use `setTimeout()` to begin the animation:

```
$("div").each(function(i){
    var div = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
    div.animate({left: "+=200"}, {duration: 3000, queue: false})
            .delay(2500).animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 500});
    },i*1000);
});
```

See this updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eP2C3/36/

Comment: But if I remove it, opacity animation will start after left animation and 2500ms delay. And I need it to start at the end of left animation.

Comment: I see I've updated my answer. You can use `setTimeout()` to begin the animation instead of `delay()`.

Comment: and is it real with delay?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was slightly more complicated than I thought, but I think i have an answer now. Unfortunately you cannot use jQuery `animate` function, because it is queueing your animations and you cannot apply two animations with different settings at the same time (at least to my knowledge).
So you can try something like this:

```
$('div').each(function (i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.delay(i * 1000).animate(
        {
            left: '+=200'
        },
        {
            duration: 3000,
            start: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    setInterval(function () {
                        $this.css({opacity: '-=0.04'});
                    }, 30);
                }, 2500);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

The `setInterval` function is used to create the animation effect. I hope this helps.
JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eP2C3/44/

Comment: But " I need them to fadeOut while moving", and now the fade out after left animation is end

Comment: its also not the one I need( Now opacity and left starts at the same time.

Comment: another try, i hope it's what you're looking for :D

Comment: Mark S' answer is better :)